# Handling network exceptions in an event driven distributed system

Tags: exception, redis, rabbitmq, distributed-computing

I have implemented a RESTful API and , at some updates on some endpoints , I need to connect to some RabbitMQ server , or a Redis Server. And these messaging will help the events unfold further. My question is , how do I handle the network exceptions on this scenario ?

For example , If Task A is updated , I first update the status of the Task in the DB (mongodb for example) , and then submit a message on some RabbitMQ server for notification of another consumer on another microservice. OR I might need to update some counter on a Redis server.

```
* API REQUEST - update Task A
*serving request:
* update Task A on DB
* send message to RabbitMQ about the change (ERROR ? socket timeout. do I retry indef ?)
* update a counter on Redis (ERROR ? socket timeout - do I retry indef?)
```

How do I handle if I have , say, "Socket Timeout exception" on trying to connect RabbitMQ or Redis ? Should I try to revert the changes on the Database and simply return HTTP 500 ?
Or should I try to write down to some file or DB , about this failure , so that It can be tried later again ?

The system is event driven. There are no daemons that keep checking for missions from a DB , so this said message had to be sent to RabbitMQ at that moment of the received API request. Or the update on the Redis server should have been made on the moment of the received API request

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what you're trying to do and what are you dealing with.

Is the network reliable? Are the services reliable? Is it a big problem if something gets replayed/retried? Is it a big problem if some task is left pending? How do you deal with inconsistent states?

You mention a timeout when publishing to RabbitMQ (I assume with confirms), but what happens if RabbitMQ confirmation message is lost? or confirms it and there's other error down the flow?

In the end, the architecture will be determined by your risk model, considering which risks are acceptable and which aren't.

A usual approach is trying to create idempotent flows and retry them if they fail (so multiple updates don't matter), but that needn't to be the case.

If you absolutely need the system to be consistent at every point in time, you may need to implement a distributed transactions algorithm that involves all the pieces.